# Debugging SpringBoot MVC service application 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

A web application I've been working on recently the past like 2 weeks maybe for whatever reason when I finally tested it - won't seem to even enter the method that I have to return a JSON list of objects.  I have included the Jackson library and Spring Boot Web, Tomcat, Data-JPA, Hibernate, MySQL, and a library to allow me to access JSP files.  The index.jsp comes up but I almost feel like Spring Boot is giving me that free of charge as it's not even entering **that** method.  I have been having the issue for a few days but trying to resolve it on my own - I found another answer that suggested to put a breakpoint inside one of the Spring classes but when I "debugged" it through Eclipse, it didn't even stop at that class - something about pattern matching - One answer suggested adding a context to the application.properties file - didn't help.  I've reduced it to as simple as I think I can get it.  Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?  Before my code, the project is on Github at: https://github.com/sfulmer/Scheduler.git

Here's my controller:

```
package net.draconia.schedule.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import net.draconia.schedule.beans.Event;

import net.draconia.schedule.dao.EventDAO;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class ScheduleController
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private EventDAO mObjDAO;
    
    protected EventDAO getDAO()
    {
        return(mObjDAO);
    }
    
    //@GetMapping("/events")
    @RequestMapping(value = "events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Event> getEvents()
    {
        logger.debug("I got here");
        
        return(getDAO().getList());
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index()
    {
        return("index");
    }
}
```

Here is the DAO interface - I'll show the class if necessary but this is what the controller looks at:

```
package net.draconia.schedule.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

import net.draconia.schedule.beans.Event;

public interface EventDAO
{
    public Event getEventById(final long lId) throws EntityNotFoundException;
    public List<Event> getList();
    public void remove(final Event objEvent);
    public void removeById(final long lId);
    public Event save(final Event objEvent);
}
```

The Event class is so long but if I need to include it, I will.  The application.properties file is here:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schedule
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = R3g1n@ M1lL$ 1$ My Qu3eN!
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
server.servlet.contextPath=/scheduler
```

and here is my Application class(with the SpringBootApplication annotation):

```
package net.draconia.schedule;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"net.draconia.schedule.controller"})
public class ScheduleApp implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return(builder.sources(ScheduleApp.class));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ScheduleApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to Spring Boot but haven't ever ran into this problem ever before as I work with it at work and it works fine but we use entirely REST services there and I am using JSP files as well as sorta end-points that respond with JSON but you can't respond from REST services with JSP views so unfortunately I can't copy work's project to get that working or I would *sigh*  Any thoughts on how I can get this working or what I am omitting?

Comment: Can you check your scan package name in ScheduleApp class?

Comment: I added some packages since I posted the question - still not fixing the problem though.  I have now "net.draconia.scheduler.dao", "net.draconia.scheduler.controller" - I may try adding my beans folder as there are JPA annotations there to see if that helps - I had created a barebones test program fresh scrach (no beans or DAO and it hit the function - added the bean, no change, added the DAO and it complained that the DAO class was not present in the bean factory so I added to that and thought maybe it would fix it in the original project, nope :-(

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're mixing things from Spring and Spring boot, and that's getting problems on loading beans, as you're probably changing the annotations load order or loading other beans rather than spring boot defaults as expected. For example, you `implements WebMvcConfigurer`, but you aren't providing any WebMvc Configuration, like a `ViewResolver` bean

My advice is to follow this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

and use only the annotations from spring boot if using spring boot, or spring if using spring (they're similar, but not exactly the same, configuration is different).

Anyways, you can check loaded beans in Spring application context (Inject it in Application class) with `ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()` method and see if your controller is there (i guess not).

Answer (score 0):

By looking into code, my first impression is that, you have some typo in here:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"net.draconia.schedule.controller"})
```

Your controller class package name has `net.draconia.schedule.controllers`.

So can you please correct your `scanBasePackages` with proper package name.
If that is not the case, please update full stack trace along with `GET` request which you are submitting into application. Will take a look & update answer accordingly.